# Python dtype advanced compound types

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, types, numpy-ndarray

I am currently following a Tutorial to show me how to create some advanced component types.
I can't really understand the example of the author , here it is:

```
tp = np.dtype([('id', 'i8'), ('mat', 'f8', (3, 3))])
X = np.zeros(1, dtype=tp)
print(X[0])
print(X['mat'][0])
```

Output[1]

```
(0, [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]])
[[ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.]]
```

Can anyone exaplain me please with simpler examples ? Appreciate your time!

Comment: It looks like it is a 3x3 matrix with an id number.  how about... dt = np.dtype([('id', 'i8'), ('XYZ', 'f8', (3))]) … place = np.zeros(1, dtype=dt) … array([(0, [0., 0., 0.])], dtype=[('id', '<i8'), ('XYZ', '<f8', (3,))])

Comment: Looks at `tp['id']` and `tp['mat']`.  Try it with `X = np.zeros(3, dtype=tp)`.

Answer (score 0):

This type of arrays are known as structured arrays

They contains structures instead of individual elements.

```
tp = np.dtype([('id', 'i8'), ('mat', 'f8', (3, 3))])
```

tp defines the type of structure S contained inside the array

Numpy will translate this into something like this in C language:

```
typedef struct S{
    int64_t id; //int64 <=> i8
    double[3][3] mat; //f8 <=> double
}

X = np.zeros(1, dtype=tp) #X is an array of one element (X.shape == (1,)).

print(X[0]) #Prints the first and last element of the array 


print(X['mat']) #this is like selecting the column 'mat'
print(X['mat'][0]) #first element of the column 'mat'; shape=(3,3)
```

Another example:

```
first = (0, np.zeros((3,3)))
second = (1, np.ones((3,3)) )
Y = np.array([first, second], dtype=tp)
Y['id']  # equivalent to [0, 1]
Y['mat'] # equivalent to [zeros((3,3)), once((3,3))]
```